# Laravel Routes- Get id from url

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

This is my "parent" route:

```
Route::resource("services", "ServicesController");
```

It works great, I now need this "child" route to work. It's as follows:

```
Route::resource("services/{id}/reviews", "ReviewsController");
```

The idea is that for each service_id, I can write a review that will pick the id of that service and persist that into my database along with the form data but this doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

However, when I create the "child" route as follows:

```
Route::resource("reviews", "ReviewsController");
```

I get the following error, meaning the service_id is missing:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'service_reviewed' doesn't have a default value
```

How can I get this route below (as seen above) to work as I think it would pick the service_id from the url and persist it to my database (since it's a foreign key in my reviews table) along with the form data:

```
Route::resource("services/{id}/reviews", "ReviewsController");
```

Comment: Do you need a full api for your route (since you're using `resource`) or you simple need a single route for `services/{id}/reviews`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

```
Route::get("services/{id}/reviews", "ReviewsController@method");
```

and you need to define it **before** your resource route.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses guys. I found that route nesting was the answer:

```
Route::resource("services", "ServicesController");

Route::resource("services.reviews", "ReviewsController");
```

And then in my ReviewsController:

```
public function create($id){


    $user_service = User_service::findOrFail($id);

    return view ("reviews.create")->withUser_service($user_service);


}
```

But that had to be accompanied with a specific url in my create view:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['services.reviews.store', $user_service->id]]) }}
```

Now what's bugging me is the store method. I need to pass the id parameter into it since the user_service_id (id) is a foreign key in my reviews table:

```
public function store(ReviewsRequest $request, $id){


    $service_review = new Service_review($request->all());

    \Auth::user()->service_reviews()->save($service_review);         

    return redirect("reviews");
```

I know I should use Eloquence to achieve this but the syntax is not yet clear to me.